# How do I get head deployment link (url)?

Tags: google-apps-script

After using GA's new editor, I don't know where to get the head link.
Does anyone know where it is?

The image below shows a menu where you can view links in the legacy editor.
I don't know where this menu is in the new editor.

[legacy editor's menu button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bCxBN.png)

[Dialog to view links](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qzDA6.png)

Answer (score 1):

There is a big blue button : "Deploy"

Then to get deployed URL : "Manage Deployment"

Or to get Head deployment (dev) : "Test Deployment"

Documentation related to deployments : https://developers.google.com/apps-script/concepts/deployments

Comment: In this blue deploy button only versions 1 to the current appear, version 0 (head) does not appear.

Comment: you are right, I edited my answer